# User search option. age: in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I am planning ahead for my user search engine and have a quick question. Users will be able to search other users based on name, location, age, activities, gender, etc.

As it stands now I index name and email for login purposes. There currently isn't an age column in the database, only Dob. Will I need to add an age column and index that column in order to make searches faster?

Will I need to index each column that users will be able to search by?

Comment: Approximately how much users will be in the users table? What database system you planned to use (postgresql, mysql) ? For example if more than 10 000 it's definitely better to store an age as integer an add index, otherwise the DB engine must subtract all dob dates from the current value and search in it. With age it just simply use some kind of b-tree to filter values, but it depends on how much different values will be in age array... If there will be 10 thousand 18 years old, indexes does not help you at all, indexes are useful on columns with different values and foreign keys.

Comment: I am using postgresql and i am expecting upwards of 3 million + users. So I assume I will need the age column but not to index it? the same with gender search?

Comment: I read a few articles how to store gender in database and a lot of users ends with CHAR(1). Try to read some articles about database query optimizers (CBO or RBO) :)